# React With Reffer https://github.com/jackfranklin/universal-react-example

Tags: reactjs

When I change My React App TO SSR  Shows An error Like Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"

Comment: ...and what's your question?

Comment: I change https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedReduxCode   to SSR 
    ..........Solution For That Error